# Smooth Scroll to Top Button with jQuery isn't working

Tags: jquery

The button works pretty well, it appears after the user scrolls down 300px, and it scrolls smoothly to the top when the user clicks-- I just can't get it to disappear after the page scrolls to the top. what do i need to do?

you can see it on this codepen: http://cdpn.io/bukAm

Relevant element is .scrollup

here's what's in my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function(){

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>300) {
      $(".scrollup").fadeIn('slow');
    } else {(".scrollup").hide();}

  });

  $(".scrollup").click(function(){

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},600);
    return false;

  });

});
```

Comment: } else {(".scrollup").hide();}  try to add $ to work hide method

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues:

- Your code to hide the icon was missing the `$`
- You care about the `window`'s scroll position

Updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ksouI

```
if ($(window).scrollTop()>300) {
    $(".scrollup").fadeIn('slow');
} else {
    $(".scrollup").fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that... only problem is, the button still doesn't fade out after you scroll back to the top. Any ideas?